# Typescript Auth0 module

Tags: typescript, module, auth0

I have the following .d.ts file (extract of it)

```
declare const Auth0: Auth0Static;

declare module "auth0-js" {
    export = Auth0
}
```

Now in my .ts file I am using the following

```
import { Auth0 } from 'auth0-js';
```

I get the following error

**auth0-js has no exported member Auth0**

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

The `auth0-js` library does not export anything named `Auth0`.

If you just want to import everything then change your import to `import * as Auth0 from 'auth0-js'`. Otherwise your can import the individual exports like `import { WebAuth } from 'auth0-js';`

Also, are you making your own typings? Otherwise you can just use the already available typings from `npm install @types/auth0-js`.

Make sure your `tsconfig.json` is configured to lookup the typings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In our angular-cli project we successfully set it up by

`npm install auth0-js @types/auth0-js --save`

and importing paths that you need like `import { WebAuth } from 'auth0-js';`

Answer (score 0):

You can include auth0 script in index.html

and inside your auth.ts. You can use

```
declare var auth0: any;
```

That avoids any name not found errors that typescript might raise.